# how to create object on 1>stack only and not on heap and 2>heap only not on stack

Tags: c++, object

To create object on heap only->
1>is there anything wrong in the code

```
class B 
{ 
~B(){}  
public: 
void Destroy() 
{ 

delete this; 
} 

}; 

int main() { 
B* b = new B(); 
b->Destroy(); 

return 0; 
}
```

why you cant create object of class b on stack
2>

```
class B
{
    B(){}   
    public:
    static B* Create()
    {

        return new B();
    }

};

int main() {
    //B S;
    B* b = B::Create();

    return 0;
}
```

3>how to create object only on stack and not on heap

Comment: You mention creating on the stack. Were you planning on doing that? Something like `B b;` perhaps ?

Comment: To force creation of an object on heap only, make the destructor private. As a result if the user declares the object on stack, compiler will not be able to access the destructor during stack-unwinding and hence results in compile time error. To force creation of object on stack only, make `operator new` private to the class, as a result user will not be able to create the object using the `new operator`

Comment: I am wondering why one wants to restrict where the object is created? I feel that this a client decision and not one the class itself should care about. What is the use case for this?

Comment: @jens For use case, singleton is implemented as heap only.

Comment: @qqqqq Well, singletons are an anti-pattern I strongly discourage. For C++, the best way to create a singleton is as a local static variable in the singleton method and not on the heap. And still, why should the class be bothered with being created on the heap or stack?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to create object only in Heap make destructor as private. Once the destructor is made Private, the code will give compiler error in case on object creation on stack. If you do not use new the object will be created on stack.

1) Object creation only on Heap

```
class B 
{ 
    ~B(){}  
    public: 
         void Destroy() 
         { 

            delete this; 
         } 

}; 

  int main() { 
  B* b = new B(); 
  b->Destroy(); 

  return 0; 

}
```

Nothing seems to be wrong with above code, If you try to create the object on stack `B b1` it will give compiler error.

2) For restricting the object creation on heap, Make operator new as private.

You code

```
class B
{
    B(){}   
    public:
    static B* Create()
    {

        return new B();
    }



};

int main() {
 //B S;
   B* b = B::Create();

   return 0;
 }
```

This code is still creating object on Heap/Free store as it is using new.

3) To create object only on stack not on heap, the use of new operator should be restricted. This can be achieved making operator new as private.

```
  class B 
   { 
    Private:
        void *operator new(size_t);
        void *operator new[](size_t);
}; 

  int main() { 
  B b1; // OK
  B* b1 = new B() ; // Will give error.

  return 0; 

}
```

Comment: @JamesRoot If destructor is made private the code which will try to create object on stack will not compile. As compiler will not able to map a destructor for the object , when object goes out of scope. Yes we can also make constructor private, but that will restrict any type of object creation outside the class

Comment: You'd still be allowed to allocate B on the heap by making it a member of another class.
`class C { B b; };
C c = new C();`
Working Example: https://ideone.com/frDHJ6

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Concrete Data Type idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Concrete_Data_Type): To control object's scope and lifetime by allowing or disallowing dynamic allocation using the free store (heap)